# How can I prevent users from selecting multiple answers in my quiz?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The issue that I am having is that once a user selects an answer and then clicks 'Submit Answer' and receives their feedback they are able to continue to click around and select other answers before progressing onto the next question. How can I prevent a user from being able to do that once they submit one answer?

```js
let score = 0;
let currentQuestion = 0;
let questions = [{
    title: "At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
    answers: ['7', '10', '11', '13'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
    answers: ['Dunder Mifflin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Slytherin', 'Gryffindor'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Rubeus Hagrid', 'Albus Dumbledore', 'Severus Snape', 'Minerva McGonnagle'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Where is Hogwarts School for Witchcraft and Wizardry located?",
    answers: ['France', 'USA', 'UK', 'New Zealand'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What form does Harry Potter's patronus charm take?",
    answers: ['Stag', 'Eagle', 'Bear', 'Dragon'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "What type of animal is Harry's pet?",
    answers: ['Dog', 'Owl', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Who is not a member of the Order of the Phoenix?",
    answers: ['Remus Lupin', 'Siruis Black', 'Lucious Malfoy', 'Severus Snape'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What is not a piece of the Deathly Hallows?",
    answers: ['Elder Wand', 'Cloak of Invisibility', 'Resurrection Stone', 'Sword of Gryffindor'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "In which house is Harry sorted into after arriving at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Slytherin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Gryffindor', 'Hufflepuff'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What prevented Voldemort from being able to kill Harry Potter when he was a baby?",
    answers: ['Love', 'Anger', 'Friendship', 'Joy'],
    correct: 0
  },
];



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.start a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.start').hide();
    $('.quiz').show();
    showQuestion();
  });

  $('.quiz').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  $('.quiz a.submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('button.selected').length) {
      let guess = parseInt($('button.selected').attr('id'));
      checkAnswer(guess);
    } else {
      alert('Please select an answer');
    }
  });

  $('.summary a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    restartQuiz();
  });

});

function showQuestion() {
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
  $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').append(`<button id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</button>`);
  }
  showProgress();
}

function showIncorrectQuestion(guess) {
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
  $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    let cls = i === question.correct ? "selected" : guess === i ? "wrong" : ""
    $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').append(`<button id="${i}" class="${cls}">${question.answers[i]}</button>`);
  }
  showProgress();
}

function checkAnswer(guess) {
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  if (question.correct === guess) {
    if (!question.alreadyAnswered) {
      score++;
    }
    showIsCorrect(true);

  } else {
    showIsCorrect(false);
    showIncorrectQuestion(guess);
  }
  question.alreadyAnswered = true;
}

function showSummary() {
  $('.quiz').hide();
  $('.summary').show();
  $('.summary p').text("Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered " + score + " out of " + questions.length + " correctly! Care to try again?")
}

function restartQuiz() {
  questions.forEach(q => q.alreadyAnswered = false);

  $('.summary').hide();
  $('.quiz').show();
  score = 0;
  currentQuestion = 0;
  showQuestion();
}

function showProgress() {
  $('#currentQuestion').html(currentQuestion + " out of " + questions.length);
}

function showIsCorrect(isCorrect) {
  var result = "Wrong";
  if (isCorrect) {
    result = "Correct";
  }
  $('#isCorrect').html(result);
  $('.navigate').show();
  $('.submit').hide();
}
$('.navigate').click(function() {
  currentQuestion++;
  if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
    showSummary();
  } else {
    showQuestion();
  }

  $('.navigate').hide();
  $('.submit').show();
  $('#isCorrect').html('');
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #837F73;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #950002;
  padding: 60px;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: #950002;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #FFAB0D;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid #222F5B;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #222F5B;
  color: silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FCBF2B;
}

.quiz button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 26px;
}

#currentQuestion {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#isCorrect {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.quiz,
.summary {
  display: none;
}

.quiz ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #398C3F;
}

.wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Harry Potter Quiz</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <header role="banner">
    <div class="start">
  <h1>How Well Do You Know Harry Potter?</h1>
  <a href="#">Start Quiz</a>
</div>
  </header>


<main role="main">
<div class="quiz">
  <h2>Question Title</h2>
  <div>
    <button>Choice</button>
    <button>Choice</button>
    <button>Choice</button>
    <button>Choice</button>
  </div>
  <a class="submit" href="#">Submit Answer</a>
  <a class="navigate" style="display:none;" href="#">Next Question</a>
  <div id="currentQuestion"></div>
  <footer role="contentinfo">
  <div id="isCorrect"></div>
  </footer>
</div>
</main>


<div class="summary">
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <p>Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered x out of y correctly! Care to try again?</p>
  <a href="#">Retake Quiz</a>
</div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

    <!--jQuery script when using JSBin-->
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>-->

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use [radio elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) instead of `<button>`

Comment: Adding `disabled` prop after submit and removing on next question click

Comment: `<input type="radio" name= "choice" value="someValue1"> <input type="radio" name= "choice" value="someValue2">` something like this.

Comment: *document.getElementsByTagName("button").disabled = true;* will disable the buttons. By the way, I had all the answers right. What do I win?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have declared a variable called `buttonClickable` and used it as a flag on every button click. when the user submits the answer, buttonclickable turns false and when ever you are rendering a new question buttonclickable turns true.

```js
let score = 0;
let currentQuestion = 0;

let buttonClickable = true;

let questions = [{
    title: "At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
    answers: ['7', '10', '11', '13'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
    answers: ['Dunder Mifflin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Slytherin', 'Gryffindor'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Rubeus Hagrid', 'Albus Dumbledore', 'Severus Snape', 'Minerva McGonnagle'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Where is Hogwarts School for Witchcraft and Wizardry located?",
    answers: ['France', 'USA', 'UK', 'New Zealand'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What form does Harry Potter's patronus charm take?",
    answers: ['Stag', 'Eagle', 'Bear', 'Dragon'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "What type of animal is Harry's pet?",
    answers: ['Dog', 'Owl', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Who is not a member of the Order of the Phoenix?",
    answers: ['Remus Lupin', 'Siruis Black', 'Lucious Malfoy', 'Severus Snape'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What is not a piece of the Deathly Hallows?",
    answers: ['Elder Wand', 'Cloak of Invisibility', 'Resurrection Stone', 'Sword of Gryffindor'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "In which house is Harry sorted into after arriving at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Slytherin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Gryffindor', 'Hufflepuff'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What prevented Voldemort from being able to kill Harry Potter when he was a baby?",
    answers: ['Love', 'Anger', 'Friendship', 'Joy'],
    correct: 0
  },
];



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.start a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.start').hide();
    $('.quiz').show();
    showQuestion();
  });

  $('.quiz').on('click', 'button', function() {
    if(!buttonClickable) return;
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  $('.quiz a.submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('button.selected').length) {
      let guess = parseInt($('button.selected').attr('id'));
      checkAnswer(guess);
    } else {
      alert('Please select an answer');
    }
  });

  $('.summary a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    restartQuiz();
  });

});

function showQuestion() {
  buttonClickable = true;
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
  $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').append(`<button id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</button>`);
  }
  showProgress();
}

function showIncorrectQuestion(guess) {
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
  $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    let cls = i === question.correct ? "selected" : guess === i ? "wrong" : ""
    $('.quiz div:nth-child(2)').append(`<button id="${i}" class="${cls}">${question.answers[i]}</button>`);
  }
  showProgress();
}

function checkAnswer(guess) {
  buttonClickable = false;
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  if (question.correct === guess) {
    if (!question.alreadyAnswered) {
      score++;
    }
    showIsCorrect(true);

  } else {
    showIsCorrect(false);
    showIncorrectQuestion(guess);
  }
  question.alreadyAnswered = true;
}

function showSummary() {
  $('.quiz').hide();
  $('.summary').show();
  $('.summary p').text("Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered " + score + " out of " + questions.length + " correctly! Care to try again?")
}

function restartQuiz() {
  questions.forEach(q => q.alreadyAnswered = false);

  $('.summary').hide();
  $('.quiz').show();
  score = 0;
  currentQuestion = 0;
  showQuestion();
}

function showProgress() {
  $('#currentQuestion').html(currentQuestion + " out of " + questions.length);
}

function showIsCorrect(isCorrect) {
  var result = "Wrong";
  if (isCorrect) {
    result = "Correct";
  }
  $('#isCorrect').html(result);
  $('.navigate').show();
  $('.submit').hide();
}
$('.navigate').click(function() {
  currentQuestion++;
  if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
    showSummary();
  } else {
    showQuestion();
  }

  $('.navigate').hide();
  $('.submit').show();
  $('#isCorrect').html('');
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #837F73;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #950002;
  padding: 60px;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: #950002;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #FFAB0D;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid #222F5B;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #222F5B;
  color: silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FCBF2B;
}

.quiz button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 26px;
}

#currentQuestion {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#isCorrect {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.quiz,
.summary {
  display: none;
}

.quiz ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #398C3F;
}

.wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Harry Potter Quiz</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <header role="banner">
    <div class="start">
  <h1>How Well Do You Know Harry Potter?</h1>
  <a href="#">Start Quiz</a>
</div>
  </header>


<main role="main">
<div class="quiz">
  <h2>Question Title</h2>
  <div>
    <button>Choice</button>
    <button>Choice</button>
    <button>Choice</button>
    <button>Choice</button>
  </div>
  <a class="submit" href="#">Submit Answer</a>
  <a class="navigate" style="display:none;" href="#">Next Question</a>
  <div id="currentQuestion"></div>
  <footer role="contentinfo">
  <div id="isCorrect"></div>
  </footer>
</div>
</main>


<div class="summary">
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <p>Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered x out of y correctly! Care to try again?</p>
  <a href="#">Retake Quiz</a>
</div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

    <!--jQuery script when using JSBin-->
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>-->

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Having skimmed through your JS, I'm assuming that the feedback shows on the same page as the question, rather than a new page resulting from submitting it to a server.

When you display the feedback, add a `disabled="disabled"` property to the item in question, so that your user can't change it. Alternately, hide the selection and display an `<output>` element: `<output>Your Answer: USA<br />Correct Answer: UK</output>`

Answer (score 1):

disable All button after checking answers.

```
$('button').prop('disabled', true);
```